# Convert a list of todos and concentrate the tasks

Tags: elixir

I have a list of to-dos:

```
[
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7}, %{todo: "a", priority: 1}},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7}, %{todo: "b", priority: 2}},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7}, %{todo: "c", priority: 3}},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-02], weekday: 1}, nil},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-03], weekday: 2}, %{todo: "d", priority: 2}},
]
```

But I need a list like this:

```
[
  %{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7, tasks: [%{todo: "a", priority: 1}, 
                                                   %{todo: "b", priority: 2}, 
                                                   %{todo: "c", priority: 3}]},
  %{date_value: ~D[2017-01-02], weekday: 1, tasks: []},
  %{date_value: ~D[2017-01-03], weekday: 2, tasks: [%{todo: "d", priority: 2}]}
]
```

How can I convert the first version into the second version?

I understand that `[head | tail]` is a way to recursively walk through this list to compile a new list. But I don't understand how I can collect all the `todo` from one day over such a recursion to put them together into their own list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, group the list by the date component, with the value function returning only the task. This will create a Map from the date component to a list of tasks. Then, convert the Map back to a list, in the process also removing the `nil` values since you don't want them according to the sample output.

```
list = [
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7}, %{todo: "a", priority: 1}},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7}, %{todo: "b", priority: 2}},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01], weekday: 7}, %{todo: "c", priority: 3}},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-02], weekday: 1}, nil},
  {%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-03], weekday: 2}, %{todo: "d", priority: 2}},
]

list
|> Enum.group_by(fn {date, _} -> date end, fn {_, task} -> task end)
|> Enum.map(fn {date, tasks} ->
  date |> Map.put(:tasks, Enum.filter(tasks, &(&1)))
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[%{date_value: ~D[2017-01-01],
   tasks: [%{priority: 1, todo: "a"}, %{priority: 2, todo: "b"},
    %{priority: 3, todo: "c"}], weekday: 7},
 %{date_value: ~D[2017-01-02], tasks: [], weekday: 1},
 %{date_value: ~D[2017-01-03], tasks: [%{priority: 2, todo: "d"}], weekday: 2}]
```

(Maps are unordered, so this output is identical to your expected output.)